# Duplicate Sub Query

Tags: mysql, sql, django-orm

I was looking into my django orm sql queries to improve them.

The django made query something like this

```sql
SELECT `A`.`id`,
  `A`.`name`,
  -- ......,
  -- This is same as the HAVING PART --
  COUNT(
    CASE
      WHEN `AU`.`user_id` IN (
        SELECT U0.`to_user_id`
        FROM `user_friends` U0
        WHERE U0.`from_user_id` = 51342
      ) THEN `AU`.`id`
      ELSE NULL
    END
  ) AS `friends_visits`
FROM `A`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `AU` ON (
    `A`.`id` = `AU`.`location_id`
  )
WHERE (
    `A`.`is_active`
    AND `A`.`is_approved`
  )
GROUP BY `A`.`id`
HAVING COUNT(
    CASE
      WHEN (
        `AU`.`user_id` IN (
          SELECT U0.`to_user_id`
          FROM `user_friends` U0
          WHERE U0.`from_user_id` = 51342
        )
      ) THEN `AU`.`id`
      ELSE NULL
    END
  ) > 2
ORDER BY `friends_visits` DESC;
```

Although the having part can be written like this.

```sql
--- .........
HAVING `friends_visits` > 2 
--- .........
```

I want to know is there a performance difference or sql just knows that it's the save query and places the value of `friends_visits` without recalculating it.

I'm using mysql 5.7.

Thanks.

Comment: *"Although the having part can be written like this."* - That is only true with certain DBMS. Since `HAVING` is logically evaluated before the `SELECT` this is not possible in all DMBS, it is likely that the people at Django opted not to use this proprietary feature for their generated SQL as it won't work for all vendors. With regard to performance, the true answer would lie in the execution plan, but I'd be amazed if MySQL didn't recognise that the two expressions were the same and evaluate them only once

Comment: You can use the `EXPLAIN` clause on both queries and compare their execution plans. MySQL Workbench has a Visual Explain capability that provides a visual representation of `EXPLAIN` output.

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceFernandes and @GarethD. I just checked that mysql5.7 is running extra query ;(. If I change it to `HAVING friends_visits > 2 ` it reduces the subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

- `IN ( SELECT ... )` is not efficient.
- Turning the expression inside out would avoid collecting `NULL` only to not count them.
- `INDEX(from_user_id,  to_user_id)` would be beneficial

So, I think

```
COUNT( CASE WHEN ( `AU`.`user_id` IN (
                            SELECT  U0.`to_user_id`
                                FROM  `user_friends` U0
                                WHERE  U0.`from_user_id` = 51342
                                     )
                 )
            THEN `AU`.`id`
            ELSE NULL END 
     ) AS `friends_visits`
```

can be replaced by

```
( SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM `user_friends` U0
      WHERE U0.`from_user_id` = 51342
        AND to_user_id = AU.user_id
) AS `friends_visits`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I'm using django orm, and there are many optimizations that aren't done by orm. Like the example above, the subquery is called multiple times, and more Django doesn't have CTEs.

Comment: Don't get me started on how ORMs are useful for toy projects, but rarely scale.  Sorry, but it may be time to abandon Django.

Comment: Well, we are in a world full of faults. Most of them are created by humans for themselves, just like orms. xD xD